# onDraw not called in a custom view added to overlay with windows manager

Tags: java, android

I'm tearing my hair out over why my view only draws the first time.  I've created a  custom view that draws a bitmap for me.  It's onDraw looks like this:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            Paint p = new Paint();
            canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, p);
            Log.e(TAG, "CALLED");
}
```

Then in my main activity I set it up like this:

```
mDView = new drawableView(this, null);
mDView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
mDView.setOnClickListener(this);
mDView.setClickable(false);
mDView.setFocusable(false);
mDView.setWillNotDraw(false);
int id = 201;
mDView.setId(id);
wm.addView(mDView, topLeftParams);
```

wm is my windows manager

```
wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
```

Then finally I have a call back function that gets called in my main activity:

```
@Override
public void onFillEvent()
{
    Log.e(TAG, "onFillMain");
    mDView.setBitmap(mDepth.mFrameBuffer);
    mDepth.fillDepthBuffer();
    int id = 201;
    getParent().findViewById(id).invalidate();
    mDView.invalidate();
    mDView.postInvalidate();

}
```

I've tried all three methods to invalidate the view in the windows manager.  But what happens is the first bitmap it drew stays on the screen.  I never see onDraw log "CALLED" after the first time.  I do see my call back getting called all the time and logging onFillMain.

I later tried adding an onLayout method to my custom view but that doesn't call and log either. I'm pretty stuck what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to trigger a change in the overlay, you have to call

```
wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
wm.updateViewLayout(mDView, topLeftParams);
```